# How to save DDB to file?

Tags: winapi, gdi+

I wanted to ask if it is possible to save DDB to file ? I know that you can save DIB, so it means that I would need to convert DDB to DIB before saving. Is there any other way ? thx

Comment: It's just data.  Any kind of data can be saved to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "Device Dependant" DDB bitmap is dependant on the display device to interpret its pixel data.  A file is not dependant on the display device.  So the answer is no, you cannot save a DDB to a file and have it be a meaningful .BMP file.  It has to be saved as a "Device Independant" DIB bitmap instead.  Besides, that is what the official .BMP file specification requires anyway.